# Uno - error during uploading with library

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, library, visualstudio

I'm writing the code in *VS Code* on *IO Platform*. Yesterday i finished my code and uploaded it to the Arduino Uno. It works fine. Next day i launched the VS Code and i changed the code a bit, then i uploaded it and i got the error.

Error:

```
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_7'
NewPing.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\uno\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

I am using the libary `NewPing.h`. The code should does this: If is distance more than 20cm, the the buzz makes the sound and turns on the red led. If distance is less than 20cm, the blue led turns on

The code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>  //It has to be there, because the arduino ide in VS Code will not work.

#include <NewPing.h>

#define echo_pin 3
#define trig_pin 4
#define max_range 450

#define red_led_pin 7
#define blue_led_pin 9
#define buzz_pin 10

int distance = 0;

NewPing sonar(trig_pin, echo_pin, max_range);






void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(red_led_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blue_led_pin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(buzz_pin, OUTPUT);
}



void loop() {

  distance = sonar.ping_cm();
  delay(50);

  if (distance > 0) {
          distance = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
      distance += sonar.ping_cm();
      delay(50);
    }
    distance /= 4;

    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println("cm");

    if (distance > 20) {

      digitalWrite(blue_led_pin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(red_led_pin, HIGH);
      tone(buzz_pin, 1500);
      tone(buzz_pin, 800);
    }

    else {

      digitalWrite(red_led_pin, LOW);
      digitalWrite(blue_led_pin, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

I don't undersand, what has changed. I tried to import again the libary https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries by importing the *.zip file, also installing in IDE.

Comment: Please look into "NewPing.h". Is the line `#define ENABLE_TIMER_BASED_PING 1` commented out or active?

Comment: Did you change the pin numbers from before? If yes, which exactly?

Comment: @chrisl How can i look into? How to open that file?

Comment: I'm not sure, why you are asking be that. It is a simple text file. You can open it with any text editor. All the source files are pure text files, that can be edited easily with any text editor

Comment: I was able to compile your code without errors (using the Arduino IDE). I used [this NewPing library](https://github.com/livetronic/Arduino-NewPing) from github. Please give us information about, which NewPing library you have used exactly.

Comment: @chrisl I am using this library https://github.com/as000fm/NewPing-1.9.1/blob/master/NewPing.h Version 1.9.1. I tried to upload it with Arudino IDE to my arduino and it works. But the VS Code still doesn't work and i am getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not a VSCode expert, but that sounds like VSCode is using the wrong library files for compilation. Cannot say, how to fix that

Comment: @chrisl sure. But THANKS you for fix my problem with Arduino! And if i may ask, which code editor do you use for arduino or for any other language? I don't really like how the IDE looks, that's why i am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conflict of interrupts. Both the internal `tone()` command and the `NewPing.h` use Timer 2 by default, which makes them mutually exclusive.

However you can change `NewPing` to not use a timer by editing the `src/NewPing.h` file and setting `TIMER_ENABLED` to be `false`:

```
    #define TIMER_ENABLED true      // Set to "false" to disable the timer ISR (if getting "__vector_7" compile errors set this to false). Default=true
```

Comment: I wrote it to the my code under line with including th libary, but nothing has changed. What exactly and where should i type it? Finally, I installed the library based on instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pSVzV4PdiA

Comment: @AuthorCliment Majenko asked you to change the corresponding line in the `NewPing.h` file, not in your sketch. Open the `NewPing.h` file (which you can find somewhere in your libraries folder) with a text editor, find that line and change it according to Majenkos answer

Comment: @chrisl I dound that line. I changed it to false. And I'm still getting the same error.